# How to use logical OR with QuerydslBindings?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, querydsl

I'm using QueryDSL with querydsl-value-operators and I'm having some problems to use logical OR with QuerydslBindings. This is my code:

```java
@Repository
public interface PaperRepository extends JpaRepository<Paper, Integer>,
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Paper>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QPaper> {

    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QPaper root) {

        bindings.bind(root.author1)
                .all((path, values) -> ExpressionProviderFactory.getPredicate(path, values));

        bindings.bind(root.author2)
                .all((path, values) -> ExpressionProviderFactory.getPredicate(path, values));

    }

}
```

I'm using querydsl-value-operators to filter a paper by the author's name, the url is something like this: /papers?author1=John&author2=Jhon . The problem is that the way the QuerydslBindings were written it generates a AND logical and of course with no results.

How can I edit these bindings to use logical OR with this two attributes (author1 and author2)?